# java arraylist has any function like c++ vector capacity() or the mechanism is different?

Tags: java, c++, arraylist, vector

As below, I could get how many elements in t (0 actually), but I do not know the real size of t capsized. In c++, the capacity() could return 100.

```
// in Java
ArrayList<Integer> t = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);
System.out.println(t.size());  // 0

// in C++
vector<int> t;
t.reserve(100);
std::cout << t.size() << std::endl;  // 0
std::cout << t.capacity() << std::endl; // 100
```

How can I get capacity for t in Java?

Comment: Your C++ code is all wrong. It makes the question unclear.

Comment: sorry, i have fixed it.

Comment: It still wouldn't compile. Anyway, `t.size()` is 100. `t.capacity()` who knows.

Comment: with the help, it could be compiled and run, and the result is given in comments. I

Answer (score 2):

You can't get at that information (without reflection), but you can perform certain actions that have to do with the capacity.

- If you want to ensure a certain capacity (for instance, so that the next 100 inserts won't trigger a resize in the middle), you can use [`ensureCapacity(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity-int-)
- On the other hand, if you want to *reduce* the capacity (to save memory, potentially at the cost of a new array allocation and copying over the elements), you can use [`trimToSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize--)

Both of these functions are declared on `ArrayList`, not `List`, so your variable would have to be typed to that specifically (as you did in your code).

Comment: If i call clear(), after i use ensureCapacity(100). Do I still get 100 when i call size()?

Comment: No, you'd get 0. `size()` always refers to how many elements are in the list, regardless of the capacity of array that the list uses internally.

Comment: I mean, the real capacity, it is still 100? or it will be collected by gc?

Comment: The real capacity will remain at 100. The elements in the array will be set to `null` (potentially allowing them to be GC'ed, if the list was the last thing holding onto them), but the array will still be held by the ArrayList and will thus not be eligible for GC. (I have to head to bed now, sorry -- good night!)

Answer (score 0):

No, Java doesn't have a method that tells you the capacity of an `ArrayList`. That sort of information is considered an *implementation detail*, which client code shouldn't worry about. The `ArrayList` is free to manage its underlying array as it sees fit. In fact, it's usually preferable from a design standpoint to simply use `List`, or in certain cases `RandomAccessList`, instead of trying to work with a specific implementation.

Note that `ArrayList` *does* have two methods that can be used to advise it about the client's intentions: `ensureCapacity(int)` tells the list that it should be ready to hold at least that many items, and `trimToSize()` tells the list that no additional members are expected and that it should shrink its array to only be large enough to hold the current items.